# Linux (on Vmware) keeps timing out instantly when not doing any network activity

Tags: networking, kali-linux, vmware

I have recently installed Kali Linux flavor of Linux as a virtual machine in my Windows 7 Host.

After setting up the Linux, I opened `VM -> Removable Devies -> Network Adapter -> Settings` and enabled the following configurations,

- `Connected`
- `Connected at Power on`
- `Bridge: Connected directly to a
  physical Network`

after that, when I run the `ifconfig` command, I see the following output,

```
root@kali:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:34:a2:c1  
          inet addr:192.168.0.130  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe34:a2c1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13782 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3253 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:9988969 (9.5 MiB)  TX bytes:370134 (361.4 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:28 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:28 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1680 (1.6 KiB)  TX bytes:1680 (1.6 KiB)
```

If I try to `ping` my guest OS from the host, I get,

```
C:\Users\Alik>ping 192.168.0.130 -t

Pinging 192.168.0.130 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.5: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.0.5: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.0.5: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.0.5: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.130:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Control-C
^C
```

This is only when I am not doing anything in the guest OS.
But as soon as I am performing any activity in the guest OS, then I am able to ping the guest successfully.

For example,

In guest OS,
I opened browser and visit google.com, as soon as google loaded, I started getting ping reply in my host os,

```
Pinging 192.168.0.130 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.5: Destination host unreachable
Reply from 192.168.0.5: Destination host unreachable
Reply from 192.168.0.5: Destination host unreachable
Reply from 192.168.0.5: Destination host unreachable
Reply from 192.168.0.5: Destination host unreachable
Reply from 192.168.0.5: Destination host unreachable
Reply from 192.168.0.5: Destination host unreachable
Reply from 192.168.0.5: Destination host unreachable
Reply from 192.168.0.5: Destination host unreachable
Reply from 192.168.0.130: bytes=32 time=2506ms TTL=6
Reply from 192.168.0.130: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.130: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.130: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.130: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.130: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.130: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
```

I have also tried using the `static` ip address in the guest OS by editing `/etc/network/interfaces` but the issue remains the same.

Here is the output of my `ipconfig` in the host,

```
Windows IP Configuration


Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Home
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f49a:847d:4877:86c2%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.5
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7cb6:45ef:7ca0:cb22%19
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.203.34
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c57e:f209:9e2:92eb%20
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.217.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.Home:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Home

Tunnel adapter isatap.{64A5DB56-CAC6-45A4-9569-E52762E8306D}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{760AD03F-B3C0-4297-AF67-031BF0F4B681}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

Could anyone please guide me what could possibly be the issue? Why is the Guest os timing out when it is not performing any internet operation?